# convert List of hashmap into set

Tags: java, generics, collections, hashmap, set

i want to cast `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` into `Set<StudentInfo>`

i have method

```
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> getStudentData(studentId);
```

i want to convert the result into Set so i used

```
Set<StudentInfo> studentFilteredInfo = new HashSet<>();
List<Map<String, Object>> studentCompleteRecord = getStudentData(1005);
studentFilteredInfo.addAll((Collection<? extends StudentInfo>studentCompleteRecord ));
```

initially when i executed on localhost it with java 8, eclipse and tomcat 8 it is working fine.

when i tried to build it with maven

```
mvn clean package
```

it will through an Error:

incompatible types: `java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>`

```
cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<? extends com.school.model.StudentInfo>
```

Comment: That never worked. That does not even compile.

Comment: Casting isn't just magic, seems like you are trying to convert between two completely incompatible types. You need some way to convert your Map<String,Object> into a StudentInfo

Comment: i know. i also used to do that using loop or iterator. but eclipse suggested me this and i tried it. i wondered it is working.
it is still working correctly but when i deployed it on my cloud environment it  it uses maven to build and it through error.

Answer (score 9):

You are **mistaken**: there is no **casting** from `List<Map<String, Object>>` into some `Set<Whatever>`!

Casting basically means: you **know** that some "Object" has a more specific type; thus you tell the compiler: "you can safely assume that this thingy here is something else in reality".

But that means: in reality (at runtime), that "thingy" really is "something else"! And alone the generic types that you provide in your question make it very clear: you can't be doing a **cast** here!

In other words: you have to write **code** that **iterates** your List of Maps; to extract that information that is required to create new **StudentInfo** objects. Then you collect those newly created objects; and put them into a new Set; which you then can return from your method!

And finally: always avoid "concrete" implementation types; you used `List<HashMap<...` - instead, you should go for `List<Map<...` !

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code to explicitly convert a `Map<String,Object>` to a `StudentInfo` instance. Suppose `StudentInfo` has a method like this:

```
static StudentInfo create(Map<String, Object> info) {
  String name = info.get("name");
  Transcript transcript = info.get("grades");
  return new StudentInfo(name, transcript);
}
```

Then you would need to iterate over each element in the list and use your method to convert the `Map` instances to `StudentInfo` objects.

With lambdas:

```
  Set<StudentInfo> studentFilteredInfo = studentCompleteRecord.stream()
    .map(StudentInfo::create)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Without lambdas:

```
  Set<StudentInfo> studentFilteredInfo = new HashSet<>();
  for (Map<String,Object> e : studentCompleteRecord) 
    studentFilteredInfo.add(StudentInfo.create(e);
```